# Getting fancybox and hover remove icon to work on the same image

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I'm using the tips on this question [Overlay thumbnail with remove image button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909850/overlay-thumbnail-with-remove-image-button) to get a overlay hover remove icon to be shown on thumbnails on my page.

But I'm also using fancybox and I can't seem to get both working at the same time. Because they both need the `<a>` element.

Right now, this is my code.

```
<div class="image-thumb" style="display: inline-block; background-image: url('<?php echo base_url().$path.$thumb; ?>');" align="center">
<a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo base_url().$path.$file->filename; ?>" rel="galery1" title="<?php echo $file->description; ?>">
    &nbsp;
</a><br>
<?php echo $file->description; ?></strong>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.image-thumb { 
position: relative; 
width: 150px;
height: 150px; 
/* apply background-image url inline on the element since it is part of the content */
background: transparent url() no-repeat center center;
}

.image-thumb a { 
display: none;
position: absolute; 
top: 2px;  /* position in bottom right corner, assuming image is 16x16 */
left: 126px; 
width: 22px; 
height: 22px; 
background: transparent url('/path/to/remove-icon.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
}   

.image-thumb:hover a { 
display: block;
}
```

In the `<a>` element, if I set the class to fancybox, it works, and if I remove it, the hover icon works. Out of ideas to get them both working. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you post the CSS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *...Because they both need the `<a>` element*

Actually, you can bind fancybox to any html element other than `<a>` using the special fancybox attributes `data-fancybox-*` so get rid of the class `fancybox` in your `<a>` tag and add it to its parent `<div class="image-thumb fancybox"...`

Then set the `href`, `title` and `group` attributes like :

```
<div class="image-thumb fancybox" data-fancybox-href="<?php echo base_url().$path.$file->filename; ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery1" data-fancybox-title="<?php echo $file->description; ?>" style="...">
    <a>&nbsp;</a><strong><?php echo $file->description; ?></strong>
</div>
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r7Xqn/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Can you try,

```
.image-thumb a.fancybox { 
display: none;
position: absolute; 
top: 2px;  /* position in bottom right corner, assuming image is 16x16 */
left: 126px; 
width: 22px; 
height: 22px; 
background: transparent url('/path/to/remove-icon.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
}   

.image-thumb:hover a.fancybox { 
display: block;
}
```

and just keep fancybox as the class name for your a element.

Comment: I was thinking about maybe using two hover images. One for delete, and one to trigger fancybox. But no clue to how it could be done. I suck at CSS. :/

Comment: What javascript are you putting in your page to get fancybox to work? can you post that as well?

Comment: Nothing custom really, just using the most basic fancybox usage possible, which is putting the class `fancybox` on the `<a>` element for my images. Fancybox just makes it work somehow.