# How to get two overlay hover icons on an image, each with a different action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have already succeeded ([Getting fancybox and hover remove icon to work on the same image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20749253)) in having my image link to an action (open fancybox) and having an icon showing on hover to delete. But this is not particularly instinctive to the user - he may feel that clicking on the image will also delete.

Can I have two separate overlay hover icons? One to expand and one to delete? This is what I've got so far:

```
.image-thumb {
position: relative;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
/* apply background-image url inline on the element since it is part of the content */
background: transparent url("") no-repeat center center;
cursor: pointer;
}
.image-thumb a {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
/* position in bottom right corner, assuming image is 16x16 */
left: 126px;
width: 22px;
height: 22px;
background: red url('/path/to/remove-icon.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
}
.image-thumb:hover a {
display: block;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="image-thumb fancybox" style="display: inline-block; background-image:     url('http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg');" align="center" data-fancybox-href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery1" data-fancybox-title="one">
<a></a><strong>description</strong>
</div>
<div class="image-thumb fancybox" style="display: inline-block; background-image: url('http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg');" align="center" data-fancybox-href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery1" data-fancybox-title="two">
<a></a><strong>description</strong>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r7Xqn/

If you go to the fiddle, you'll see where a hover icon would show. It is the delete icon. What I'd like is to have a second icon, maybe placed at the lower-left corner to trigger a different action, in this case launch fancybox.

Comment: You need to show us what you've already attempted doing first and the specific problems you've found. We're not here to just do your work.

Comment: I really have no idea how to even start. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r7Xqn/. This is what I got so far.

Comment: I just updated the question with some of that code. Also, it is unclear what you are asking, can you elaborate further, please?

Comment: Ok, added some code and more detail.

Comment: Is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/r7Xqn/2/

Comment: Almost. I need for each icon to have a different action. Right now (in your fiddle) they are both mapped to "delete". But the icons and positioning, are perfect. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution. The extended version of @Francisco Presencia

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/r7Xqn/3/)

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();

// testing
$(".image-thumb a.delete").click(function(e){
alert("this item will be removed");
e.stopPropagation();
});
$(".image-thumb a.other").click(function(e){
alert("this item will be fancybox. Hurray");
e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: Ah lol, I wasn't even sure what he meant with 'actions' and was just going to ask him. +1